# Does react native supports .error() function?

Tags: react-native

Im trying to handle a "Network request failed" error (I already allowed unsecured connections from Xcode), But when i try to do something inside the .error() function it crashes and says: .error is not a function; The fetch() works already.
here's an example of it, Im trying to run this code after a fetch function.

```html
fetch('URL',{
                'method': 'POST',
                'headers': {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                'body': data}
        )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          //Do something
          
        })
.error((error)=>{
              console.error(error);
              Actions.login()
            });
```

Comment: It's called `.catch()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React's `fetch` method returns a [Promise](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#handling-the-response), which doesnot have `.error()` method. Instead it has `.catch()` method to catch all errors when `fetch` fails.

```
fetch('URL', {
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    'body': data
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    //Do something

  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    Actions.login()
  });
```